# Squid connection refused after super simple one row in config

Tags: squid

I've just started digging in squid, installed it and run. I suppose it works (from localhost), `telnet localhost:3128` works as well as `curl https://google.com -x localhost:3182`.

I want squid to be accessible from local network. My local network is 192.168.88.0/24 (255.255.255.0). I added the next row to squid.conf just before the last row in http_access section:

```
http_access allow 192.168.88.0/24
```

Squid stopped working. I leaved only three rows in http_access block so the full section is:

```
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow 192.168.88.0/24
http_access deny all
```

curl https://google.com -x 192.168.88.2:3128 (called from local network) does not work. But the more frustrating is that previous command, `curl http://google.com -x localhost:3128` (called from localhost) also stopped working, that means that the second row somehow affects the first one.

What's the right way to write http_access block in squid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
acl rtfm src 192.168.88.0/24
http_access allow rtfm
```

Comment: A couple links just in case you need help finding the FM.  http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/